Connecting VPS to VPN makes it unreachable
So, I'm trying to connect my VPS which runs a VPN (algo, WireGuard) to another VPN (hide.me). It connects successfully (I see that via online service hosted on it), but I'm not able to connect to it via SSH, nor with WireGuard anymore. Is it possible to somehow accept incoming connections using the original address while still using the VPN for outgoing connections?
I want the traffic to go through my server, then through a hide.me server.
Hide.me executable supports the flag -s, which is described as follows: -s networks: comma separated list of networks (CIDRs) for which to bypass the VPN.
I've tried adding <my IP>/32 to it, which solves SSH problem (but I don't quite like this solution as my IP can easily change), but connecting with WireGuard makes internet completely unreachable from the connected device.
I've also tried adding <WireGuard IP prefix>.0.0/16 which didn't change anything.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The TASK of the VPN is to SPECIFICALLY make the user invisible. In that case, the "user" is your VPS, so of course it becomes unreachable. You should explain what you are trying to achieve, and outline what you have done so far to accomplish it, and then outline your specific question. Currently, we do not know what you really are trying to do, so I'm voting to close this question.

Is it possible to somehow accept incoming connections using the original address It still does that. The problem is the replies for such "connections" would still be routed into the VPN tunnel, unless you set up appropriate policy routing (ip rule in Linux), i.e. "split tunnel" based on source address (if bound), source port (e.g. ssh) or "fwmark" (with the help of "ctmark" in iptables / nftables).

@TomYan excuse my arrogance, but how do I set it up? Specifically, how to split tunnel based on port?
